# WPF distributed transaction coordinator service

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on wpf application and I have to run "distributed transaction coordinator" service in code side. 
How can I run this service in code side? (I am using c#)

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ServiceController class for this. However, this requires your users to have admin rights (or at least, the rights to start/stop services on their machine).

Example: http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/